# Calling mapview from non extending mapview class

Tags: android-mapview

I am calling the draw overlay method from the other class , I cant able to draw the overlay.I got the exception as below. Please check out and give me a solution for this.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
   at com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.boundCenter(ItemizedOverlay.java:173)
   at com.lifedots.mapoverlaydraw.MyItemizedOverlay.<init>(MyItemizedOverlay.java:34)
   at com.lifedots.BalloonItemizedOverlay.onTap(BalloonItemizedOverlay.java:124)
   at com.google.android.maps.ItemizedOverlay.onTap(ItemizedOverlay.java:453)
   at com.google.android.maps.OverlayBundle.onTap(OverlayBundle.java:83)
   at com.google.android.maps.MapView$1.onSingleTapUp(MapView.java:356)
   at com.google.android.maps.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:533)
   at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onTouchEvent(MapView.java:683)
   at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3885)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:903)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you provide the code, It seems you have used BalloonItemizedOverlay, I have used this maybe I can help, can't figure the error without the code. (Will edit if you provided the code)